# Magento, users can't login

Tags: php, magento

My magento is a new installation with a theme applied on it.

Right after user registration, user is redirected back to the signin page and there is a message "You are no longer able to access this store".

And I tried to type in the account just registered with correct password, it keeps telling me "Invalid login or password.".

I tried to go the backend of the magento, the customers are there. And even I reset password in the backend panel. I still can't login in the frontend.

I wonder if there are any special settings in magento related to this. I hope someone can help because most topics I googled are related to magento backend signing in but not in frontend.

Thanks.

My Magento version is 1.7.0.2

Comment: Are you using any third part extensions related to customer login or registration? Have you set 'Require Emails Confirmation' under create new account options?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. "Require Emails Confirmation" option remains "No".

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Magento are you using?

Is your theme a custom theme from an older version?

Since version 1.8 Magento moved their formkey for XSS to the front end.

Try adding the following to your login form.

`<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />`

If this works you will also have to add it to the checkout login pages.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I forgot to mention my Magento version in my question. I had just updated my question and it's 1.7.0.2.